# Dynamic cron job creation with springboot scheduler

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cron-task, spring-scheduled

I have a spring boot application. I want to run some ETL operations. I have a UI which defines and schedules a job. The job information is saved in db. I need to define a cron job for each of the jobs defined in db. I can have 100's of jobs that need to run. How can I programmatically add the cron jobs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Quartz. You can search with this keyword

[Quartz](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/07/quartz-2-scheduler-example.html)

[Spring Quartz](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-quartz-schedule)

[More](https://javabypatel.blogspot.com/2017/10/quartz-scheduler-spring-boot-example.html)

[Spring Boot Quartz](https://dzone.com/articles/adding-quartz-to-spring-boot)